# How To Make A Batch Program That Takes what I input into it and to output it into a .txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So Basically I wanna make a program in batch that when I start it asks me to log in and ask me for my email what I want is for the program to take what I put Like this example:
Program asks for Email I input email1234@gmail.com program takes that and stores it in a temp dir as Login.txt
I need this so when the user tries to log in again the program looks for Login.txt and immediately logs in the user without them having to start again.
This is the code:

```
@echo off
:choice
set /P c=Do you have a Account?[Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :login_succesfully
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :Cannot_Login
goto :choice


:login_succesfully

cls
Color 2
echo "Ok Login To Verify Your Identity To Use This"
cls
:choice
rem Saved in C:\Temp
set /P c=Email?

if /I "%c%" EQU "" goto :Pass
goto :Pass
pause
exit

:Pass

cls
set /P c=Password?
if /I "%c%" EQU "" goto :Download
goto :Download

:Download
cls
echo Thank You Now Starting Example!
TIMEOUT /T 3
Start https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/845027712192217159/848817832170749963/Example1234.txt
pause
exit

:Cannot_Login

cls
color C
echo "Please Create a Account and ask a Admin to Manually Verify Who You Are"
pause
exit
```

Comment: See `if /?` about `if exist`, Use `<login.txt set /p var=` to get the (first line of) a file into a variable. If needed, use `>login.txt echo %var%` to write a variable to a file.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary login systems that do not require secure protection of the content, the ntfs system offers an alternative to temporary files courtesy of Alternate data streams.

```bat
@Echo off & CD /D "%~dp0"
Goto :Main

=====:# Save function
:Save
:# Define variables for retention with a # prefix
:# and output to the !User!_Save.cmd stream by calling this function
 (For /f "Delims=" %%G in ('Set #')Do Echo(Set "%%G") >"%~f0:%#User%_Save.cmd"
Exit /B 0

=====:# User input function
:Input <Variable> <Prompt> <Descriptor>
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 Set "%~1="
 Set /P "%~1=%~2: "
 If Not Defined %~1 (
  Echo(%~3 required
  Endlocal
  Goto :Input
 )
 For /f "Delims=" %%v in ("!%~1!")Do ( Endlocal & Set "%~1=%%v" )
Exit /B 0

:Main
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 Set "#Status=New"
 Cls
:Login
 Echo(Existing users:
 For /f "Skip=6 Tokens=2 Delims=:" %%G in ('Dir /R "%~f0"^|Findstr /vc:"_Save.cmd"')Do Echo(%%G
 Echo(
 Call :input #User "Enter your username" "Username"
 If /I "!#User!" == "E" Goto :Eof

:Verify
 Cls
 (More < "%~f0:!#User!") > nul 2>&1 && (
  Call :input #Pass "Enter your password" "Password"
  For /f "Delims= " %%G in ('More ^< "%~f0:!#User!"')Do Set "Validate=%%~G"
  REM case sensitive. Spaces not permitted.
  If not "!Validate!"=="!#Pass!" (
   Echo(Password invalid. Try again Y/N?
   For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('Choice /N /C:YN')Do if "%%G" == "N" Goto :Login
   Goto :Verify
  )
 ) || (
  Echo(Create user: "!#User!" Y/N?
  For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('Choice /N /C:YN')Do if "%%G" == "N" Goto :Login
  Call :input #Pass "Enter your password" Password
  Call :input PassC "Confirm your password" Password
  If not "!#Pass: =!" == "!PassC!" (
   Echo(Passwords do not match. Spaces not Permitted.
   Pause
   Goto :Verify
  )
  (Echo(!#Pass: =!) 1>"%~f0:!#User: =!" 2>Nul || (
   Echo(Invalid Characters in Password.
   Goto :Verify
  )
  Call :Save
 )

:ReturnAction
 Echo(
 Echo([C]ontinue [R]emove User [N]ew Password ?
 For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('Choice /N /C:CRN')Do (
  If "%%G" == "R" (
   Powershell -c "remove-item -path '%~nx0' -Stream '!#User!'"
   (Powershell -c "remove-item -path '%~nx0' -Stream '!#User!_Save.cmd'") 2> nul
   Goto :Login
  )
  If "%%G" == "N" (
   For /F "UsebackQ Delims=" %%G in ("%~f0:!#User!_Save.cmd")Do %%G
   Call :input #Pass "Enter your new password" Password
   Call :input PassC "Confirm your new password" Password
   If not "!#Pass: =!" == "!PassC!" (
    Echo(Passwords do not match. Space not permitted.
    Pause
    Goto :ReturnAction
   )
   (Echo(!#Pass: =!) 1>"%~f0:%#User: =%" 2>Nul || (
    Echo(Username contains invalid characters.
    Timeout /t 3 /Nobreak
    Goto :Verify
   )
   Call :Save
  )
 )

:# exit delayed expansion environment
 Endlocal & Set "#User=%#User%"

:# Load user information from the stream.
 For /F "UsebackQ Delims=" %%G in ("%~f0:%#User%_Save.cmd")Do %%G
 Echo(Login Successful.

:# The below line is not required. It simply shows the loaded values.
 Set #

:# Your script below
 Set "#Status=Returned"
 Call :Save
```

Streams use the following syntax:

- "filepath:streamname"

Each user has two streams associated with it, `%~f0` being the path of the batch file:

- `"%~f0:!#User!"` ; which the password is saved to
- `"%~f0:!#User!_Save.cmd"` ; which is used to store all `#` prefixed user variables to for later loading

  - loading is achieved by reading and reassigning each variable stored in the stream using a `For /f` loop.

To display existing users, a for loop iterates over the output of the `Dir` command with the `/R` switch and `"%~f0"` search term, which gets filtered through the `findstr` command  via a pipe ( with `/V`switch and `_Save.cmd` match term to remove the _Save.cmd streams from the output ).

Conditional execution `||` and `&&` are used to control script flow depending on whether streams are succesfully read.

Powershell is used to remove Streams from the batch file when the user indicates they wish to remove their logged in user. (Batch has no *native* method of removing streams from a file)